# In video processing, is the z-coordinate the frame number?

Tags: matlab, video-processing, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I'm trying to perform some basic action recognition using the KTH dataset.

I'm using the 3DSIFT feature extractor from UCF [link](http://crcv.ucf.edu/source/3D). Which extracts a SIFT descriptor from a given x, y and z coordinate.

For feature detection I am using selective-STIPS [link](http://iselab.cvc.uab.es/silverage.php?q=SelectiveSTIPs), that has shown to be very effective for action recognition. According to the source code provided by the author, it produces the following output:

```
    @output : corner_points, P X 4 matrix, where P is the number of interest
%           point found in the image_stack and each interest point contains
%           4 values :: [X,Y] coordinate of the interest point, frame
%           number, scale at which it is detected.
```

Am I right to assume that the frame number provided here is also the Z-coordinate required by 3DSIFT?

I extracted STIPS from a video clip and got the required output but I am getting multiple `X` and `Y` values on every frame:

```
[71,24,1]
[54,26,1]
[86,29,1]
...
..
.
```

Is this expected output and accepted input for SIFT3D?

Comment: From what I can gather you are asking about 3rd party toolboxes or pieces of code without at a minimum linking to them.  How is anyone suppose to know how these things work without seeing the code & knowing what version of something you are running

Comment: @AeroEngy I didnt feel the need to link as I felt this was a general question, not specifically related to any of the tool boxes but general video recognition. But I have linked to the scripts now, if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from what I can tell following through 3dsift Z is equivalent to frame number when dealing with video. So the x,y, frame output from stips should work as the x,y,z input to 3dsift.